# CSS - Have div's height all the way down to another div

Tags: html, css

OK, I have this these two divs and one of them is a checkbox and the other div has text. Sometimes can be little or small. Anyway, if it's big, the box on the left will go down all the way to cover the gap it leaves if I didn't set its `height` to `100%`. However, there is a problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/4odLkzby/

See how the left div goes BEYOND that and overlaps the `.reply` div below it? How can I fix this?

Here is a better graphic to show:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it overlaps the .reply div below it?

Comment: @FirstLegion I added a photo to help you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/4odLkzby/2/

Add `position: relative` to CSS attributes of parent `(.reply)`.

Comment: top:0 and bottom:0 are redundant. Those are not needed. Putting both contradicts each other.

Comment: Thank you, I realize the power of position

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative` to reply class.

http://jsfiddle.net/4odLkzby/1/

Answer (score 0):

check out this css

CSS

```
.reply {
background: #E8E8E8;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica;
font-size: 15px;
color: #333;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#hovering-icon {
background: rgb(53, 107, 138);
color: white;
}
.hovering-answer {
background: rgb(71, 135, 172);
color: white;
overflow:hidden;
}
.reply > .icon-wrap {
background: #C4C4C4;
padding: 5px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
}
.answer-wrap {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.text-wrap {
padding: 7px 5px 7px 40px;
font-family: 'Helvetica', serif;
}
.icon-wrap {
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/rdy1u9qg/)

Comment: @DanF still issue remain?

Comment: Yes, do you not see your jsfiddle and how it's still the same problem? http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/rdy1u9qg/